# When I use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths, the cells will be deleted, but other cells will twinkle

Tags: ios, uitableview

when I use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:`,
the cells of `indexPaths`（indexPaths.count=1） will be deleted,but other cells will 'twinkle'.

Before cell is deleted:
[image: Before cell is deleted]

When cell is deleted:
[image: When cell is deleted:]

After cell is deleted,the tableview  is normal.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Reload your table view after deletion

Comment: if  reload tableview,the animation will not appear

Comment: add [self.tableView endUpdates]; before reload data –

Comment: [viewController.tableView beginUpdates];
        [viewController.data removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [viewController.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        [viewController.tableView reloadData];
    [viewController.tableView endUpdates];

it does not work!!!!!!